# Multi Paging with JSF

Tags: java, jsf-2, icefaces

I have the following scenario in my JSF (plus ICEfaces) webapp:

There is a **start page** in which the user can search or directly enter kind of file number and navigate via commandButton to the **main page** (start page stays opened). For each open page there is an entry in a map in the session bean.

Now it should be possible for an external webservice to call the main page directly with parameter in the url. As there must not be data and session confusion, it is not allowed that more than one instance of the start page and the main page exists.

How can I handle to identify whether the start or main page is already open when the webservice tries to enter the webapp, so that I might be able to show the user a hint that there is already the webapp running and open?

At the moment I enter the webapp via webservice by using parameter which is passed to the start page and in the start page it emulates a button click to open the main page with this parameter. But this way I am not able to check whether there is already a main page open.

Any ideas, suggestions, known solutions?